# InvalidOperationException when accessing ListView items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, indices, invalidoperationexception

I'm working on a small project that involves a `ListView` control. Now, when I try to access `MyListView.Items` like this:

```
if (MyListView.Items[0].Checked) { . . .
```

I get an `InvalidOperationException`! I also tried using `MyListView.CheckedIndices`, but it seems to have the same problem:
[image: Screenshot of exception]

Is there any chance someone here knows why this is happening and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Nevermind, apparently I had to invoke. My bad!

Comment: have you ever avoided nullreferenceexception first?

Comment: @LeiYang I don't see how that is relevant? Where in this do you see a possible nullref? (the screenshot shows the control itself isn't null)

Comment: i also don't see relationship between your pasted code and your picture.

Comment: @LeiYang Perhaps you didn't read properly then. I stated I tried accessing `CheckedIndices` but that throws an `InvalidOperationException`, which is exactly what the screenshot shows.